# Matrix from 2 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a vector $\vec{v} = \left<v_1, v_2, v_3\right>^T$ and a vector $\vec{w} = \left<w_1, w_2, w_3\right>^T$ and I want to write a matrix A seen bellow.

$$
A = \left[\begin{matrix}
v_1\cdot w_1 & v_1\cdot w_2 & v_1\cdot w_3 \\
v_2\cdot w_1 & v_2\cdot w_2 & v_2\cdot w_3 \\
v_3\cdot w_1 & v_3\cdot w_2 & v_3\cdot w_3
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

How can I write $A$ as a function of $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ in a more compact form?

Comment: Isn't this just $A = vw^t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=[v_1\ \ v_2\ \ v_3]^T$ and let $W=[w_1\ \ w_2\ \ w_3]$. Then $A=V.W$.